# Kotlin continuation doesn't resume

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, continuations

I'm trying to get my head around `suspendCoroutine` and `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. I think they could be useful in the following case:

1. When the coroutine is launched, check if the user is logged in.
2. If not, ask for credentials and pause the currently executing coroutine.
3. When the credentials are submitted, resume the coroutine from the same line where it was suspended.

This compiles but never makes it past "delay over", i.e. the continuation never resumes:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")

    runBlocking {
        launch {
            postComment()
        }
    }
}

var isLoggedIn = false
var loginContinuation: CancellableContinuation<Unit>? = null

suspend fun postComment() {
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        showLoginForm()

        suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> {
            loginContinuation = it
        }
    }

    // call the api or whatever
    delay(1000)

    println("comment posted!")
}

suspend fun showLoginForm() {
    println("show login form")

    // simulate delay while user enters credentials
    delay(1000)
    println("delay over")
    isLoggedIn = true

    // resume coroutine on submit
    loginContinuation?.resume(Unit) { println("login cancelled") }
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of, including moving the call to `suspendCancellableCoroutine` outside of the login check, wrapping the contents of `showLoginForm` in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`,  using `coroutineScope.launch(newSingleThreadContext("MyOwnThread")`, etc. The impression I get from reading the internet is that this is a valid use case. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing around Continuations is messy and can easily lead to the error you have...one function finishes before the continuation has even been assigned to the continuation property.

Since the login form is what you want to turn into a suspend function, that's where you should use `suspendCoroutine`. `suspendCoroutine` is low level code that you should put as low as possible so your main program logic can use easy-to-read sequential coroutines without the nested `launch`/`suspendCoroutine` calls.

```
var isLoggedIn = false

suspend fun postComment() {
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        showLoginForm()
    }

    println("is logged in: $isLoggedIn")

    if (isLoggedIn) {
        // call the api or whatever
        delay(1000)
        println("comment posted!")
    }
}

suspend fun showLoginForm(): Unit = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    println("Login or leave blank to cancel:")

    //Simulate user login or cancel with console input
    val userInput = readLine()
    isLoggedIn = !userInput.isNullOrBlank()
    cont.resume(Unit)
}
```

I didn't use `delay()` in `showLoginForm()` because you can't call suspend functions within a `suspendCancellableCoroutine` block. Those last three lines could also be wrapped in a `scope.launch` and use `delay` instead of `readLine`, but in reality, your UI interaction wouldn't be a coroutine with a delay anyway.

EDIT:

Trying to pass a continuation to another Activity would be especially messy. Google does not even recommend using multiple Activities in an app because it is difficult to pass objects between them. To do it with Fragments, you could maybe write your LoginFragment class to have a private continuation property like this:

```
class LoginFragment(): Fragment {

    private val continuation: Continuation<Boolean>? = null
    private var loginComplete = false

    suspend fun show(manager: FragmentManager, @IdRes containerViewId: Int, tag: String? = null): Boolean = suspendCancelableCoroutine { cont ->
        continuation = cont
        retainInstance = true
        manager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(containerViewId, this@LoginFragment, tag)
            addToBackStack(null)
            commit()
        }
    }

    // Call this when login is complete:
    private fun onLoginSuccessful() {
        loginComplete = true
        activity?.fragmentManager?.popBackStack()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        continuation?.resume(loginComplete)
    }
}
```

Then you would show this fragment from another fragment like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val loggedIn = LoginFragment().show(requireActivity().fragmentManager, R.id.fragContainer)
    // respond to login state here
}
```

So long as you are using a Fragment's `lifecycleScope` rather than an Activity's `lifecycleScope` and the first Fragment also uses `retainInstance = true`, I think you should be safe from screen rotations. But I haven't done this myself.

Comment: I reduced the code in my question to the bare minimum to demonstrate a problem. The real program is running on Android and launches an activity in `showLoginForm`. I need the activity to tell me when the user has successfully logged in, and I can't use `startActivityForResult` here. How can I resume the coroutine unless I keep a reference to the continuation?

Comment: See edit. I haven't tried this myself, but it's an interesting idea.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you misunderstand the concept of `suspend` functions. Calling function `showLoginForm()` does **not** start a new coroutine. Code in a single coroutine is always executed sequentially - at first you call `showLoginForm()`, it delays, it does not resume any continuations because `loginContinuation` is `null`, and then `suspendCancellableCoroutine` suspends your coroutine forever and causes a deadlock.

Starting a new coroutine that executes `showLoginForm()` can make your code work:

```
suspend fun CoroutineScope.postComment() {
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        launch {
            showLoginForm()
        }

        suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> {
            loginContinuation = it
        }
    }

    // call the api or whatever
    delay(1000)

    println("comment posted!")
}
```

This code still can fail (*), but in this particular case it does not. Working version of this code can look like this:

```
import kotlin.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")

    runBlocking {
        postComment()
    }
}

var isLoggedIn = false

suspend fun CoroutineScope.postComment() {
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->
            launch {
                showLoginForm(continuation)
            }
        }
    }
    delay(1000)
    println("comment posted!")
}

suspend fun showLoginForm(continuation: CancellableContinuation<Unit>) {
    println("show login form")
    delay(1000)
    println("delay over")
    isLoggedIn = true
    continuation.resume(Unit) { println("login cancelled") }
}
```

Also, in your example suspending coroutines is not needed. Why do we need another coroutine if we can just execute its code in the same coroutine? We need to wait until it finishes anyway. Since coroutines execute code sequentially, we will go to the code after `if` branch only after `showLoginForm()` finishes:

```
var isLoggedIn = false

suspend fun postComment() {
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        showLoginForm()
    }
    delay(1000)
    println("comment posted!")
}

suspend fun showLoginForm() {
    println("show login form")
    delay(1000)
    println("delay over")
    isLoggedIn = true
}
```

This approach is the best for your example, where all code is sequential.

(*) - This code still can cause deadlock if `suspendCancellableCoroutine` is invoked after `showLoginForm` finishes - for example, if you remove `delay` call in `showLoginForm` or if you use a multithreaded dispatcher - in JVM there is no guarantee that `suspendCancellableCoroutine` will be invoked earlier than `showLoginForm`. Moreover, `loginContinuation` is not `@Volatile`, so with multithreaded dispatcher the code can fail also from visibility issues - thread that executes `showLoginForm` may observe that `loginContinuation` is `null`.

Comment: My program is contrived because I'm trying to learn how these things work. I knew `suspend` by itself did not create a coroutine, but I thought `launch` inside `runBlocking` created the only coroutine I needed. What exactly does moving `launch` inside `suspendCancellableCoroutine` change? Does `showLoginForm` need to be a suspend function?

Comment: A single `launch` inside `runBlocking` doesn't make much sense - you can remove it, like I did in the middle snippet, and it will change nothing. `launch` is your code just creates a child coroutine to `runBlocking` coroutine, so you basically move your code from parent coroutine to child coroutine, and parent coroutine stays idle until `launch` finishes.

Comment: `launch` inside `suspendCancellableCoroutine` actually starts a new coroutine with different code, that will work while the coroutine created in `runBlocking` is suspended. You don't just "move" `launch`, you delete it from where it is completely useless and add it where it is needed.

Comment: `showLoginForm` needs to be a suspend function if and only if you call suspend functions from it. Actually, it heavily depends on the framework you use. In your case, I already stated that you don't need to create new coroutines at all, since you don't execute any code asynchronously - you just wait until an event happens.

Comment: There are some common examples of using `suspendCoroutine` for APIs based on [callbacks](https://github.com/Kotlin/coroutines-examples/blob/master/examples/io/io.kt), [executors](https://github.com/Kotlin/coroutines-examples/blob/master/examples/context/swing-example.kt) and [futures](https://github.com/Kotlin/coroutines-examples/blob/master/examples/future/await.kt). There are no `launch`es inside `suspendCoroutine` because the code inside is not suspending.

Comment: Actually, `suspendCoroutine` is more about mixing Kotlin coroutines with Java callbacks/executors/futures. If your code is based only on coroutines, there are much better ways to wait for some events to happen - `job.join()` and `kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Mutex`